# javascript email validation to allow space

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that validates emails but some customers are having problems with it if they put a space at the end of their email address and don't realise it.  I looked up other solutions on stackoverflow and tried using

```
$.trim($(element).valid());
```

but it didn't work.  Here is the code I am using below:-

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#form1').validate({
                onfocusout: function (element) {
                   $(element).valid();
                },
                rules: {
                    FirstName: 'required',
                    SecondName: 'required',
                    Email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                    reEmail: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                            equalTo: "#Email"
                        },
                    address: 'required',
                    Town: 'required',
                    County: 'required',
                    Phone: 'required',
                    Mobile: 'required',
                    reMobile: {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: "#Mobile"
                        },
                },
                messages: {
                    FirstName: 'Please enter your firstname',
                    SecondName: 'Please enter your secondname',
                    Email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
                    reEmail: 'Email addresses do not match, please retype email address again',
                    address: 'Please enter address',
                    Town: 'Please enter town',
                    County: 'Please select county',
                    Phone: 'Please enter phone number',
                    Mobile: 'Please enter mobile number',
                    reMobile: 'Mobile numbers do not match, please retype mobile number again',
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: What is the problem? is it validation failing? Because then you should validate the trimmed string rather than trim the validated string as you currently do

Comment: it's not giving an error but if there is a space at the end we still get the message, 'Please enter a valid email address'

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't validate emails with Regex.

David Celis mentions this on his [blog](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/):

> Sections 3.2.4 and 3.4.1 of the RFC go into the requirements on how an email address needs to be formatted and, well, there’s not much you can’t do in your email address when quotes or backslashes are involved. The local string (the part of the email address that comes before the @) can contain any of these characters: ! $ & * - = ^ ` | ~ # % ' + / ? _ { }
>
> But guess what? You can use pretty much any character you want if you escape it by surrounding it in quotes. For example, "Look at all these spaces!"@example.com is a valid email address. Nice.

So, pretty much, the only real requirement for an email to be valid is a `@` symbol.

Instead, you should just send them a confirmation email.

If you need to remove spaces at the end of a string, use `trim()`, but remember **emails can *sometimes* contain spaces**:

```
" test ".trim()                 //=> "test"
"     test        ".trim()      //=> "test"
" trim() is pretty cool".trim() //=> "trim() is pretty cool"
```

Comment: As I said before, I tried $.trim($(element).valid());  but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone tell me how implement trim into the function above?

Comment: I didn't get  an answer to my question